# Verified Users - is there a way to verify user by SDK?

Tags: facebook, sdk, verification, fb.ui

in the user object we have a bool "verified" field, that indicates whether or not Facebook has verified the user.

From documentation:
A user is considered verified if she takes any of the following actions: Registers for mobile, Confirms her account via SMS, Enters a valid credit card

Is there a way using SDK (example: with FB.ui or similar approach)  to show directly to a user a dialog with which ask account verification ?

Searching in the documentation i don't find nothing, but maybe i'm searching in the wrong way !!!

Thank you in advance.

Emanuele

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not implemented by facebook.
You could redirect the user to the Mobile phone verification page:
http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php but you wouldn't have any callback from the page.